# gradle if else clause for "api" or "compileOnly" dependency statement

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I have an installable app and an instant app version.
In order to reduce the APK size for the instant app version i reduced some of the features. This also means that at runtime some libraries are not used anymore. They are still needed during compilation.
In gradle there is a nice dependancy statement called "compileOnly".
Works perfectly fine. My app size get reduced exactly as I wanted it to be.
But whenever i want to compile the instantapp or installable i have to manually change all the gradle files and replace "Api" with "CompileOnly" or vice versa.

Is there a way to set a condition inside the gradle file. So I have something like:

```
//normal dependencies here.

if isInstantApp{
    compileOnly "org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:$rootProject.ASNETwitter"
}
else if (isInstallable){
    compile "org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:$rootProject.ASNETwitter"
}
```

That would save so much of my time.

PS. I am not looking for build flavors, because that is not the usecase here.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a new configuration and let either `api` or `compileOnly` extend from it:

```
configurations {
    shared
    (isInstallable ? api : compileOnly).extendsFrom shared
}

dependencies {
    shared 'my:dependency:1'
    // ....
}
```

Comment: And is that var "installable" in your example  defined in gradle? I wish to set that variable inside the gradle file from either the installable or instantapp module. Is that possible?